# How can I tell if I have a carbide tipped blade?

Tags: saw, aluminum, metal-cutting

I bought a miter saw about six years ago, and haven't used it that much over the years - however, I have worn all of the labeling off of the blade, leaving no trace of the manufacturer, blade type, or whether or not it is carbide tipped or not.

I now have a need to cut aluminum, which necessitates the use of a carbide tipped blade.  Is there any way I can determine by looking at the blade itself if it is a carbide tipped blade, i.e. are all carbide tipped blades in a special shape or color or something like that?

Comment: What they said, but be gentle when you cut the aluminum. Typical woodworking blades have a positive hook angle, which can be grabby. If you bought a blade specifically for aluminum, you'd see it has a negative hook angle. More here: http://www.carbideprocessors.com/pages/saw-blades/saw-tip-angles.html

Comment: Carbide will generally last longer, but the blanket statement "to cut aluminum... necessitates the use of a carbide tipped blade" is false. I cut thousands and thousands of pieces of thin aluminum stock with a plain old thin-rim plywood blade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Is there any way I can determine by looking at the blade itself if it is a carbide tipped blade**

As [keshlam](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/20958/keshlam) pointed out

> If the blade is carbide-tipped, each tooth will have a piece of carbide brazed/welded to the point of the tooth. That should be distinguishable to the naked eye, or with a magnifying glass if you're one of us whose close focus is no longer very good.

[image]

At date of writing, I do not know of any other commonly-encountered type of blade that could be easily confused with this.

---

<sub>*This answer [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) as it is based on other people's comments*</sub>